# Как программно открыть URL в TOR?

Tags: windows, winapi, webbrowser, tor

Если мне нужно открыть какой-то URL в, скажем, Google Chrome, я могу просто запустить его с помощью `system`, передав в командной строке URL. Или испорльзовать `ShellExecute(0,"open"...`.

Но когда я опробовал сделать так с TOR, вызывая его `firefox.exe` с параметром `-url URL`, он сначала потребовал закрыть открытый браузер, и только потом запустил новый с этим URL. Но мне интересно открыть его в новой вкладке. Как я могу этос делать?

Comment: Не понятно. Вроде речь идет вначале о браузере chrome, потом о firefox. И внезапно оказывается, что речь шла о Tor Browser?

Comment: Я рассказал, как работает с обычным (Google). Ну стоит он у меня по уморлчанию. А в составе TOR работает FireFox, причем он какой-то заточенный для работы с TOR. Вот я и спрашиваю - как работать с TOR. Ведь сам TOR - это же не браузер...

Answer (score 0):

Из доков Firefox:

-new-tab URL
Open URL in a new tab. Firefox and SeaMonkey2.x only.

-new-window URL
Open URL in a new window. Firefox and SeaMonkey2.x only.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options

Comment: Дело в том, что наверное для **обычного** Firefox это сработает, но если это Firefox в TOR - то он требует сначала закрыть уже работающий броузер. Я только что попробовал.